# Comparing Indices of two strings

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, string

I have two double quoted strings of same length, that look like this:

`"$con"` - (consists of spaces and *'s):

```
                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **
```

and `"$prot"` - (consists of letters and -'s):

```
M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ
```

How do I extract the string of letters at the same position in `$prot` corresponding to the position of *'s in `$con`.

Answer (score 1):

If your strings don't contain any newline, here's a solution using only POSIX tools. It works by putting all the characters on separate line, zipping the two files together, and extracting the lines where the first file (now the first column) had a `*`.

```
con_file=$(mktemp)
echo "$con" | sed -e 's/./&\
/g' >"$con_file"
prot_lines=$(echo "$prot" | sed -e 's/./&\
/g')
prot_extract=$(echo "$prot_lines" |
               paste -d "$con_file" - |
               sed -n 's/^* //p' |
               tr -d '\n')
```

Another, perhaps more straightforward, and undoubtedly faster, approach is to write a loop in awk.

```
echo "$prot" | awk -v filter="$con" '{
    for (i=1; i<=length; i++) {
        if (substr(filter, i, 1) == "*") printf "%c", substr($0, i, 1);
    }
}
END {printf "\n"}'
```

Yet another approach would be to convert the filter into a list of indices. The conversion is slow but I expect this to be the fastest method if you have a very long list of proteins for each set of indices.

```
indices=$(echo "$con" |
          sed 's/\*\**/,&\n/g' |
          awk -F , 'BEGIN {start = 1}
                    /\*/ {start += length($1);
                          printf "%d-", start;
                          start += length($2);
                          printf "%d,", start - 1}')
indices=${indices%,}
echo "$prot" | cut "$indices"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Perl script to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$con  ='                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **         ';
$prot ='M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ';

@c_con = split(//, $con);
@c_prot = split(//, $prot);

@i_con = grep { $c_con[$_] eq '*' } 0 .. $#c_con;
map { print "index: $_, value: @c_prot[$_]\n" } @i_con;
```

#### Example

Running it will produce a list of indexes and values at those indexes in `$prot`.

```
$ ./extracvals.pl 
index: 24, value: R
index: 28, value: Y
index: 29, value: Y
index: 30, value: H
index: 31, value: Q
index: 32, value: F
index: 33, value: L
index: 41, value: M
index: 42, value: K
index: 43, value: A
index: 45, value: K
index: 46, value: A
index: 48, value: W
index: 67, value: G
index: 68, value: L
```

#### How it works?

The script creates 2 strings, as described by the OP, `$con` and `$prot`. These strings are then read into 2 arrays, such that each character in the string takes up a cell in the array. This is done using Perl's `split` funciton:

```
@c_con = split(//, $con);
@c_prot = split(//, $prot);
```

The 2 new arrays, `@c_con` (contains `$con`) and `@c_prot` (contains `$prot`).

We then use Perl's `grep` function to find all the indexes in array `@c_con` that have the value `'*'`. This list of indices is stored in another array, `@i_con`.

Finally we use Perl's `map` function to print the index value and the corresponding value in array `@c_prot` at a given index. The `map` function takes each value from the array `@i_con`, and evaluates the command in the curly braces:

```
{ print "index: $_, value: @c_prot[$_]\n" }
```

for each of these values. The index is stored in Perl's temporary variable, `$_`, as we `map` iterates through the array `@i_con`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked a similar solution to slm (he beat me to it!) But if the OP wants to avoid coding it all in perl:

```
#!/bin/sh

con="                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **"
prot="M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ"

# put the con and prot variables into our environment variables
export con prot

# then call perl
result=$(perl -e 'my @x = split(//, "$ENV{con}"); 
    my @i = grep { $x[$_] eq "*" } 0 .. $#x; 
    print join("", map { substr("$ENV{prot}", $_, 1) } @i );' )

# now we have your answer in $result
echo "$result"

# then once finished with con and prot, unset them from the environment
unset con prot
```

`$ENV` is a reserved variable in perl containing a hash of all the *environment* variable names and values, so getting the value of $prot (which we used `export` to set it) can simply be fetched via `$ENV{prot}`.

Rather than splitting the arrays like slm did, I used `substr` which returns a sub-string of a given string (first argument), at offset (2nd argument) of set length (3rd argument). Apart from that we appeared to use identical solutions (*rather spooky, cue Twilight Zone music*) :)

Answer (score 0):

If we can use gnu grep:

```
cut -c$(grep -Fbo '*' <<<_"$con" | cut -f1 -d: | paste -sd,) <<<"$prot"
```

I'm sure that can be golfed more, but it works fine. `-bo` causes grep to output the (b)yte-offset with (o)nly-matches (not whole lines), which as a side effect causes grep to find all the matches, not just one per line. We then manipulate that into a comma-separated list of numbers, which we can feed as a command line option to `cut`. The annoying detail is that grep thinks character indices are 0-based and cut thinks they're 1-based, so we need to shift `$con` over by one character; hence, the `_`.

```
$ con="                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **"
$ prot="M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ"
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "$con" "$prot"
                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **
M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ
$ cut -c"$(grep -Fbo '*' <<<_"$con" | cut -f1 -d: | paste -sd,)" <<<"$prot"
RYYHQFLMKAKAWGL
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using the Bash shell features (saw a `/bash` tag in the question):

```
con="                        *   ******       *** ** *                  **"
prot="M-ASDFRMKAWRGMLMI----WSGRCYYYYHQFLIMASDFRMKAMKAWWSGRCYNSHPPAAQVFYWLGLLSDVAGSALEAQ"

i=0
# Iterate until the index is less than the con string length  
while [ $i -lt ${#con} ]
do 
    # Get the current element of the con "character array"  
    c=${con:$i:1}
    if [[ $c == '*' ]]
    then
        # Get the corresponding element from the prot character array  
        p=${prot:$i:1}
        echo $i, $c, $p
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

The output is:

```
24, *, R
28, *, Y
29, *, Y
30, *, H
31, *, Q
32, *, F
33, *, L
41, *, M
42, *, K
43, *, A
45, *, K
46, *, A
48, *, W
67, *, G
68, *, L
```

Of course, you can change the `echo` statement to control what is printed.

Source: [Bash: Split string into character array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579016/147021)